# How to auto delete old mails from cpanel email accounts

Tags: email, cpanel

I have connected one of my mail accounts from a cpanel hosted account to my gmail account. However gmail leaves messages it things are dangerous on the cpanel server itself and over a period of time the cpanel email account gets filled up. I want to set it up such that mails older than 30 days would automatically be deleted from the cpanel email account.

Answer (score 0):

Create a script with the following

```
#/bin/sh
find /home/*/mail/*/*/cur/* /home/*/mail/*/*/new/* -type f -mtime +30 | xargs rm -f
```

and then set this script to run in cron.

You can use the following commands to get counts of old mails and sizes of mail folders

```
find /home/*/mail/*/* -name new -type d -exec du -h --max-depth=0 \{\} \; | less
find /home/*/mail/*/*/cur/* /home/*/mail/*/*/new/* -type f -mtime +30 | wc -l
```